# How to show output in a div using partial rendering concept in MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json

I am using render partial concept in MVC. Its not showing the output in div. While debugging everything is OK (Showing Staus 200 OK) but its not going inside success block.Below is my jquery function.

```
function ShowNavigation() {
var jsonObj = {
    'Display': 'Index',
    taFormula: $('#taFormula').val()
};
$.ajax(
    {
        url: "/Home/Index",
        type: "POST",
        data: jsonObj,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            var message = data.Message;
            $("#contentDiv").html(message).val();
        }
    });

}
```

My Controller code is:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection collection)
    {
        var val = collection["taFormula"].ToString();
        ViewBag.Output = GetValue(val);
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `datatype: "json"` bit. You're receiving html back from the server, not json data, but because of that setting it's trying to parse it and failing. If you had an error callback function it would go into that.

Also, you don't need the `.val()` on `$("#contentDiv").html(message).val();`

Try adding an error handler to the ajax call and see if that gives you any more information:

```
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        alert(status + " : " + error);
    }
```

Try this for your json object:

```
data: JSON.stringify(jsonObj),
```

You might need to include [json.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) for older browsers.

Comment: I have made both changes as you said but no luck.

Comment: Now it's showing an alert which shows "error : Internal Server Error". What does it mean?

Comment: It means there's an error on the server. Put a breakpoint inside your Action and see if it's getting through there ok.

Comment: There is no error inside action. But in firebug when I debug then its not going inside succes block and displaying this error "Invalid JSON primitive: Display.".
I changed my jsonObject as
   var jsonObj = { "Display": "Index", "taFormula": "2" };
but still its throwing same error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3619/discussion-between-sharad-and-richard-d)